# wireless not detected in 14.04 fresh install

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom

I did a fresh install of 14.04 and now my wireless is not working. I don't see it in the status bar. Using unity desktop.

```
03:00.0 network controller [0280]: broadcom Bcm43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]]
0c:00.0 Ethernt controller [0200] : realtek semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 pci express gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (Received 07)
```

I don't have an wired connection for the laptop. Writing from phone.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Please do not respond with new information in comments - edit your question with this detail.  Please also edit your question with more hardware information and logs as per the linked in my comment above.

Comment: connect your laptop via a wired connection is the easiest way.

Comment: What's the not so easy way? I can Probably download packages from my phone and put them in the laptop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 2):

Your Broadcom 14e4:4359 uses bcmwl-kernel-source. It and its dependency dkms are on the installation DVD or USB. Insert the install media and navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag and drop the bcmwl deb package to your desktop. Do the same with pool > main > d > dkms. Now we install the deb files. Open a terminal and:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Best way to get wifi enabled.. Specially when you don't have any other medium to connect to internet.. :) Thanks a lot..

Comment: excellent , the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer here WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx - Community Help Wiki
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access

scroll down for options without Internet connection. Requires live cd.

Comment: it worked. My faith has grown.