# I can't connect WIFI with broadcom on ACER V5-122P

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have a Acer V5 122P, only WIFI, without Ethernet port and I can't connect to WiFi,

I have this information:

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:289 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:289 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:21633 (21.6 KB)  TX bytes:21633 (21.6 KB)


$ lspci | grep Network
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e078]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
    Region 0: Memory at f0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

I found these broadcom drivers on internet:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl

but I don't know how install them, I only know basic commands.

Information for chili555: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10416148/

Comment: i have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: You need bcmwl-kernel-source. Here is a method to get them from the install DVD or USB: http://askubuntu.com/questions/460489/wireless-not-detected-in-14-04-fresh-install

Comment: @chili555 i try but i have errors, i show you it in the first message, thanks!!!

Comment: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information." What did it say? Can you please post it here and give us the link? http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555: Edited question and voted to reopen (and left you this note here so you will find it as well)  :-)

Comment: @patatas: Uhm, the 3.16 kernel makes things more complicated, since the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package in Ubuntu 14.04 is for the 3.13 kernel. You might want to go back to kernel 3.13 or install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package for 14.10.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidFoerster, I suspect that will be my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should update your kernel.. I have this same ultrabook and every distribution based on Ubuntu 14.10 and other  previous versions fails to work properly with Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and graphics. 
On the other hand, since the update to 15.04, the new available kernel is 3.19..... This one includes all the hotkeys of the V5-122p, and works perfectly with all of the hardware.

You shouldn't really update kernel unless something is really wrong. Sadly this is the case... Follow this page to update your kernel:

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/linux-kernel-3-19-3-released-install-update-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-other-debian-based-distros

Hope it helps!